# How to Click and Drag in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

What is the easiest way to enable click and drag interactions in THREE.js app ?

Want to avoid complex RayCasting and achieve functionality similar to THREE.interaction before it became outdated.

Comment: Would using `THREE.DragControls` solve your issue? https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_drag

Comment: Thanks @Mugen87 THREE.DragControls is a good thought but does not include the click events or release events

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/DragControls  Would be awesome if this Addon could just include some of the other basic events. I have always been curious why that is not default available in THREE.js